# Ordernar mediante query o php

Tags: php, postgresql

Quiero orden una tabla mediante un item desde el mayor al menor, la columna es varchar(50).

```
    ┌────────────┬───────┬────────
    │ id│ orden  | item  │ Valor  │
    ├────────────┼───────┼────────┤
    │ 1 │ 0001   │ 1     │  $100  |
    │ 2 │ 0001   │ 1.1.1 │  $200  |
    │ 3 │ 0001   │ 1.1   │  $300  |
    │ 4 │ 0001   │ 1.2   │  $400  |
    └────────────────────┴────────┘
```

Estoy haciendo la consulta en Postgres y me muestra el siguiente error. Entiendo ques un tema de lo estoy ordenando de forma `float`

```
SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "1.1.1"
```

Aqui mi query

```
SELECT x.* FROM data.produccion x order by w.item::float +0
```

La idea mia es tener un resultado en pantalla de esta forma. Que me recomiendan ordenar mediante la query o buscar una forma en `PHP`?

```
        ┌────────────┬───────┬────────
        │ id│ orden  | item  │ Valor  │
        ├────────────┼───────┼────────┤
        │ 1 │ 0001   │ 1     │  $100  |
        │ 3 │ 0001   │ 1.1   │  $300  |
        │ 2 │ 0001   │ 1.1.1 │  $200  |
        │ 4 │ 0001   │ 1.2   │  $400  |
        └────────────────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: El problema es que valores como `1.1.1` no pueden ser convertidos a float. Según tú, ¿cuál sería el valor float equivalente para `1.1.1`? Estamos además ante un error al diseñar el modelo de datos, y mientras no resuelvas ese error en su raíz, te verás obligado a inventar cosas para hacer funcionar algo que debe ser corregido a otro nivel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se parece mucho al ordenamiento por versiones, o [semver](https://semver.org/lang/es/#spec-item-8)

```
SELECT x.*
FROM data.produccion x
ORDER BY string_to_array(x.item, '.')::int[];
```

Comment: Vaya que simple thanks  budda